# Perl IO::Stringy and IO::InnerFile install test failure on Windows OS (and how to fix it)

Tags: perl

After clean installation of Active Perl (64-bit edition, version 5.24.3) on Windows 8.1 PC I needed to add Spreadsheet::Read Perl module. However, its CPAN installation failed.

Analysis of the console report showed that the root cause of failure is **IO::InnerFile** module, which was not installed. Or – better said – failure of all seven automated tests of this module. The test script is named **IO_InnerFile.t** and (in my case) it is located in the *C:\Perl64\cpan\build\IO-stringy-2.111-0\t* directory.

Answer (score 1):

The approach by jmasa didn't work for me, but this did:

In IO_InnerFile.t, change the block right after `# Create a test file` to:

```
# Create a test file
do {
    open(OUT, '>t/dummy-test-file') || die("Cannot write t/dummy-test-file: $!");
    local $\ = "\n";    ## Use `print` vs. `say` to avoid extra blank lines.
    binmode OUT, ':raw';    ## Force output of UNIX line terminators.
    print OUT <<'EOF';
Here is some dummy content.
Here is some more dummy content
Here is yet more dummy content.
And finally another line.
EOF
    close(OUT);
};
```

This localizes the change to `$/` (changed to the UNIX single-character line terminator) and uses it to output the test text to the dummy file.

Then run

`dmake test`

`dmake install`

Answer (score -1):

Soon I realized that (because of seeking) the test script **IO_InnerFile.t** can be used only on platforms where a line terminator is a single byte.
In case of M$ Windows, where the line terminator consists of two bytes \r\n sequence, seeking to absolute position does not work – simply **the test itself is not portable**.

The possible fix is adding PerlIO layer **":crlf"**:

1. Open the file IO_InnerFile.t and find the line reading:

   `my $fh = IO::File->new('<t/dummy-test-file');`

   and change it to:

   `my $fh = IO::File->new('<:crlf t/dummy-test-file');`

   Note the space between “<:crlf” and “t/ dummy-test-file”
2. Open console window and switch to the module build directory (*C:\Perl64\cpan\build\IO-stringy-2.111-0* in my case)
3. Run manually:

   `dmake test`

   `dmake install`

Note: I don’t bother with proper PATH settings and absolute file positions, which may vary.